# Why couchdb's reduce is implemented this way?

Tags: javascript, view, couchdb, couchbase, reduce

For example, this is a function that returns the sum and length of a row:

```
function(key, values, rereduce) {
  var result = {total: 0, count: 0};
  for(i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(rereduce) {
        result.total = result.total + values[i].total;
        result.count = result.count + values[i].count;
    } else {
        result.total = sum(values);
        result.count = values.length;
    }
  }
  return(result);
}
```

It looks like you have to define:

- A way to reduce all elements.
- A way to group partial reductions (??)

Why is this so weird? A tradicional approach could be described as simple as:

```
reduce = {
    op: function(accumulated,val){
        return {total:accumulated.total + val, count:accumulated.count++};
    },
    initial: {total:0, count:0}
}
```

Which holds enough information to either reduce the entire array and update it for new values...!

Comment: Other than to say, "that is the way it was designed and that the existing pattern has an analogue in many programming languages making it easier to use potentially", what are you looking for? The first MapReduce pattern was designed with functional programming languages in mind. APIs are unfortunately very opinionated. :)

Comment: I'm looking for understanding what's going on there, if this is just a matter of style or if maybe it's part of how couchdb works.

Answer (score 2):

The `reduce` phase is repetitive because it makes storage/caching easier. You should imagine the result of reduce functions as a tree. To reduce a certain contiguous subset of nodes, you can largely use pre-calculated reduction values (and a few original ones), such that you don't have to descend the entire tree/re-calculate values for all of the nodes within the queried range.

I hope that clears it up a little, it's kind of hard to explain.

Comment: Nice succinct explanation.